# How to add Json object to existing json file in java

Tags: java, json

I have this json objects in  demo.json

```json
{
  student: {
    name: "cc"
    age : 20}
  }
]
```

want to add employee details like

```json
{
  student: {
    name: "cc"
    age : 20
  },
  employee: {
    name: "cc"
    age : 20}
  }
}
```

please suggest how to add

Comment: you mean 'add' like read-modify-write?

Comment: Yes, to an existing json file i need to update the employee details. Yes read-modify-write

Comment: I got that but where exactly are you stuck? Do you already have a piece of code? that would be useful.

Comment: I know how to add  individual objects inside student node using Jackson but i want to add entire "Employee" into the file.

Comment: well tbh I never directly used JSON in java, but I'm pretty sure you should be able to read it either with an ObjectInputStream or a simple Scanner, modify it with whatever methods are provided by a JSONObject and finally write it back with an ObjectOutputStream or a simple FileWriter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to merge them then this might be helpful

```
JSONObject merged = new JSONObject(Obj1, JSONObject.getNames(Obj1));
for(String key : JSONObject.getNames(Obj2))
{
  merged.put(key, Obj2.get(key));
}
```

Comment: i did some modification and it worked. thanks

Comment: great to hear that

Answer (score 1):

First create some POJOs:

```
class Person {
  public String name;
  public Integer age;
}

class Demo {
  public Person student;
  public Person employee;
}
```

Then you can use Jackson...

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Demo demo = mapper.readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/demo.json"), Demo.class);

Person employee = new Person();
employee.name = "dd";
employee.age = 43;

demo.employee = employee;
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(demo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's JSON Object behaves similar to Java-Native *Maps*. So just read your file into a JSONObject and add a new value using `.put()`:

```java
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(
  "{ \"student\": { \"name\": \"cc\", \"age\": 20} }"
);
JSONObject employee = new JSONObject();
employee.put("name", "cc");
employee.put("age", 20);
jo.put("employee", employee);
```

Note that this is not very object-oriented, Marcs answer is the Java way to do it.